# Check if a word exist inside a .txt file (GFI MAX)

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, compare

I need to implement a script in GFI Max that can check if a specific word (say "Finished") exists inside a text file (.txt)

I would like to be able to return a FALSE or TRUE value.

This script can be js, vbs, cmd, bat.

Thanks in advance,
C

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Have you 'googled' more than 2 secondes ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show a bit of search effort nor providing code

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
public static bool FindWord(String text,String word)
{
String[] words=text.Split(' ');
for(int i=0;i<word.Length();i++)
{
   if(words[i]==word)
     return true;
}
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You should not compare `String` with `==` in Java.

Comment: so change to     .equals()